# Take a photo and add a comment to it

Tags: photos, notes

I'd like to take a picture of something and add some comments/notes (e.g. while shopping, take a pic of something and make a note of its price). Doesn't have to be anything fancy.

How to achieve that?

Comment: If you have a Samsung device and a stylus then this is built in.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote has that capabilty as well. You take a picture and add a title and notes

Comment: People should be made aware that Evernote only provides a paltry 60MB of free uploads per month (yes, you read that right... just 60MB... not 60GB).  They have had that meager limit for many years without any increase as technology progressed.  Thus, one cannot really effectively use Evernote in this way with their free plan.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used the Samsung Note (with stylus).  It has tools built in.  However, my wife used to use this before getting a Note.

[ScreenMaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.capture.screenshot)

Blurb from their site (and I am not associated with it)

> Screen Master is a free, easy-to-use, no rooting required screenshot & photo markup tool. With Screen Master, you can capture screen by touching the floating button or shaking device, lets you take screenshot on your tablet, phone or other Android device the easy way!
>
> Screen Master also provides a variety of annotation features such as crop, add text, pixelated image, draw arrow, rect, circle and more. Lets you easily edit and markup your screenshot and quickly share it with your friends!